# Who Leaves Roses in Bamboo Cups?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I'm bathing in my swimming pool, but I only get wet when I'm diving.
>   I'm a great big Boss, like the President himself; I am important even to the High King.
>
> On my birthday, I'll completely disappear; follow me, and you'll do just the same.
>   If you then track me down, at the end of the pursuit, you'll pant and sweat, but I still won't look lame.
>
> At your leisure, take a guess at my actual name! It should perfectly fit every clue.
>   Gee, there's no pressure! Keep it casual if you want, but please explain the white space too.

Comment: Do you have to explain the last 2 lines?

Comment: @PotatoLatte Certainly.

Comment: Is this now considered solved?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm going to try this and hope it fits:

> **suit** - this puzzle stores an  x-large number of matches

I'm bathing in my swimming pool, but I only get wet when I'm diving.

> bathing suit, swimming suit, wet suit, diving suit

I'm a great big Boss, like the President himself; I am important even to the High King.

> big suit, *Hugo* Boss suit, Trump suit, High card by suit or king suite

On my birthday, I'll completely disappear; follow me, and you'll do just the same.

> birthday suit is disappeared because it is no suit, follow suit, the same - suit

If you track me down, at the end of the pursuit, you'll pant and sweat, but I still won't look lame.

> tracksuit, end of the pur**suit**, pantsuit, sweatsuit, lamé (gold!) suit

At your leisure, take a guess at my actual name! It should perfectly fit every clue.

> leisure suit, GUESS (brand) suit, perfectly fit suit

Gee, there's no pressure! Keep it casual if you want, but please explain the white space too.

> g-suit for pilots, pressure suit, casual suit, white suit, space suit

Who Leaves Roses in Bamboo Cups? - discovered by El-Guest and Gareth McCaughan - thanks!

> [Leaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaves_(card_suit))  - Leaves are one of the four suits in German-suited decks of playing cards.
>
>  [Roses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roses_(card_suit)) -  one of the four suits in a Swiss deck along with Shields, Acorns and Bells. (El-Guest)
>
>  [Bamboo suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahjong) - Mahjong has three suits: bamboos, characters, and dots. (Gareth)
>
>  [Suit of cups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suit_of_cups) -  one of the four suits of Latin-suited playing cards. (El-Guest)

As a final touch, distinction to [**jafe**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe), this triple paragraph bespoke puzzle is designed  as a

> three-piece suit. Thanks Bass :)

Comment: This is an impressive answer! Just to help you out, maybe [roses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roses_(card_suit)) and [bamboo](https://bertoni.com/en-gb/craftsmanship/style-and-fit/bamboo-suit) and [cups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suit_of_cups)? Hope this helps!

Comment: @El-Guest I agree with the first and third of your suggestions but think there is a better option for the second.

Comment: If we're really going all the way with this, there's also [leaves](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Green-Leaves-Hunting-Ghillie-Suits-Camouflage-Military-Tactical-Hunting-Shade-Clothes-Breathable-Sports-Leaf-Style-Ghillie/32849144828.html), or the more jokey version of [leaves](https://www.etonline.com/meghan-markle-and-patrick-j-adams-suits-exits-have-left-a-void-says-gabriel-macht-exclusive-101008)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan and it's from a game that I really enjoy playing, too! Here's another one for [bamboo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bamboo_suit)

Comment: Yeah, that's the one.

Comment: Good catch, @GarethMcCaughan -- haha it wasn't my first thought since we call them "sticks" instead of "bamboo".

Comment: Thank you El-Guest and Gareth for all those! That leaves leaves - maybe the foilage has foiled me.

Comment: Nicely done! I tried to build this puzzle so that it operates on two levels simultaneously, I think you nailed almost every clue in the "hidden embedded wordplay" layer, but I think there are a couple more left on the largely overlapping "more or less direct riddle clue" layer.

Comment: Thanks @Bass for your sharp well-dressed fitting puzzle. I learned things from the  great title (thanks to El-Guest and Gareth) and you tricked me at the start as was literally counting white spaces :P

Comment: Oh, but you should! Or more precisely, you should count the number of pieces the paragraph breaks divide the puzzle into :-)

Comment: rot13[guerr-cvrpr fhvg]? :) Amazing riddle.

Comment: @jafe - excellently observed - ( I was hung up on four) but that's neat!